# How to make a responsive form in Shopify?

Tags: css, shopify

I have been trying to figure out how to make a custom field form that is responsive on Shopify.

```
        <div class="one-whole">
           <div class="one-half">
            <label for="groom_name">Groom's First Name</label>
            <input required type="text" id="groom_name" name="properties[groom_name]" placeholder="Groom">
           </div>
           <div class="one-half">
            <label for="bride_name">Bride's First Name</label>
            <input required type="text" id="bride_name" name="properties[bride_name]" placeholder="Bride">
           </div>
            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            <input required type="text" id="last_name" name="properties[Last Name]" placeholder="Last Name">
            <label for="wedding_date">Wedding Date</label>
            <input required type="date" name="wedding_date">

            <label for="city">City</label>
            <input required type="text" id="city" name="properties[City]" placeholder="City">
            <label for="state">State</label>

        </div>
```

That is the code and this is what I get.

I have tried doing `whole` and `one-half` and separating each input into its own div.  The always seem to be left justified and now wrapping.

I would like Groom Name and Bride Name to be on the same line.  But when on mobile to collapse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is about css not liquid or shopify.

The classes your are looking for are documented [here](https://shopify.github.io/Timber/#grid).

Try something like `grid__item small--one-whole medium--one-half`